# Share session ID from CLI to browser

Tags: php, session, sessionid, websocket, phpwebsocket

I have a websocket connection from the browser to a php script running as a websocket server on CLI.

I have the client send its session_id that was on the server i know which user has which session.

It works perfectly to read the $_SESSION of the individual users.

i do (on the server side [my CLI code]):

```
$sess_ini = ini_get('session.save_path');
$save = file_get_contents("$sess_ini/sess_$sessionID");
session_id($sessionID);
$sessions = explode("|",$save);
$_SESSION['values'] = (isset($sessions[1])?
                        unserialize(trim(urldecode($sessions[1]))):array());
```

Then when i manipulate $_SESSION['values'] on the CLI server side it does not get reflected on the client session and the session is not manipulated. how do i make it so the manipulated session is sent back to the client?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you get the $sessionID?. I can't make it work.... The CLI sessionID is different from the Web sessionID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in my code.

The session was being saved, i just neglected to output it before it was changed so it looked like it never changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could write sessionId to users table in DB
And than in CLI and Web your must use this:

```
session_id($sessionFromDb);
```

Comment: no no. i am able to get the session. thats fine. but changing it so that it reflects on the client side is not working

Comment: You could use this http://ru.php.net/session_write_close, or maybe no permissions to write session file?

Comment: And, are you sure that in Web and CLI sessionId is no diffrent?